# I think it's an animal

Tags: idiomatic-language

When answering the question "what kind of animal does fear make you think of?"
Does my answer sound idiomatic and grammatical? Should the same construction be repeated? Or should I use "It makes me think of an animal that got trapped" instead?

"I think it's an animal that got trapped."

Comment: I would repeat the construction. Are you sure that the question does not require the responder to name an animal, e.g. 'Fear makes me think of a mouse'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey so I should use "It makes me think of an animal that got trapped". Right? I think it's unnecessary to name an animal.

Comment: Why would fear make you think of an animal? And is it an animal's fear, or yours?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - it looks like an open-ended question with many possible answers.

Comment: "an animal that got trapped" isn't a *kind* of animal. A type of animal means some kind of category of animal, like big animals, or cats, or reptiles or insects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is so odd that I would need to ask what the person was asking.

The trouble with answering non-idiomatic questions is that you don't really know what the person is asking. They might mean something completely different.

I can see four different possible meanings to the question, with different answers.

1. What kind of animal you think of when you are afraid?
2. What species of animal do you associate with the emotion "fear"?
3. WHat species of animal makes you feel afraid?
4. In what state is an animal that is afraid?

Your interpretation is 4,  "An animal that is trapped".  It is not natural nor idiomatic to repeat the question, instead a "fragment" such a this noun phrase is sufficient.

It isn't idiomatic to say "I think it's..."  That is used when a person is testing you:

> What is the name of the planet nearest the sun?
>
> I think it's Jupiter!
>
> You're wrong. It's Mercury.

If someone is asking for your feeling, and there is no right or wrong answer you don't use "I think it's"  Can you see why the following exchange is wrong?

> What is your favourite food?
>
> I think it's pizza!
>
> You're wrong. It's noodles.

But (4) seems to be the least likely interpretation.  More likely the person is asking about the species that you associate with fear.  (If it is the animal's fear you might say "mice", or if it is your fear you might say "crocodiles")

And the literal meaning is  (1) What is the animal that you think of when you are afraid.  This question is unanswerable to me, because I don't think about any particular animal when I am afraid.

Comment: do you mean in your pizza example using "it's" is not idiomatic? The answer should be just "pizza". But in my original sentence what should I use?

Comment: Yes.  You use "I think it's" to speculate. It's weird to speculate about what you own favourite food is.  And in your example you could use the bare noun phrase "cats"  (or whatever) But note the first paragraph.  The question is so unclear that my actual "answer" would be "What do you mean?"

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation.  Is "It's noodles" also wrong? In your example sentences?

Comment: Not really wrong, but a bit pointless.  There's no need ot make a full sentence to answer a simple question like that.

Comment: @JamesK - Keep in mind that the original question includes the word *think*, so it would not be odd for the answerer to include *think* in the answer.  As you say, the answerer would not say, *I think **it's***.  They would say, *I think **of***.  *What type of animal do you think of when you're afraid?*   *I think of an ocelot, terror of the jungle.*

Comment: Yes, The question is so odd to be almost incomprehensible and I would not attempt to answer it, but I would ask for clarification.  The question "What animal does fear make you think of?" is odd to the point of being meaningless @EllieK-Don'tsupporther  (ps who is "her", and why shouldn't I support her?)

Answer (score 2):

Does your answer sound grammatical: yes

Does your answer sound idiomatic: no

In this context, the word *kind* has two possible meanings:

> 1 b: a specific or recognized variety // what *kind* of car do you drive
>
> 2: fundamental nature or quality : essence // a difference in degree but not in *kind*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kind)

Of these, the first is more likely.  Usually, when someone asks "what kind of animal" they're expecting an answer like, "an Arabian horse", "a lion", "a bird" - i.e. a breed, or species, or class.

That second definition can be seen in a sentence like this:

> Lions raised in unacceptable and inappropriate conditions end up living horrible lives out in the bush if they're not properly re-introduced into the wild...Drakenstein Lion Park is a safe haven for these kinds of lions.

[News 24](https://www.news24.com/parent/family/parenting/travel/feeding-time-at-the-zoo-20081027)

In this case, *kind* refers to a *fundamental* aspect of the lions: their upbringing in inappropriate conditions.

While not exactly incorrect, it would be unusual to use the word *kind* to refer to a temporary, or unimportant condition.  The following sentence looks a little odd:

> Lions who haven't eaten in a few days can be very hungry.  These kinds of lions are the most dangerous.

Do note, however, that we sometimes use this construction as a joke:

> Person A: What kind of people eat this disgusting food?
>
> Person B: *Hungry* people.

Person A expects an answer along the lines of, *a kind of person that is fundamentally different than normal people; the kind of person who never learned what good food tastes like; the kind of person who doesn't have any sense of taste.*

Person B responds in an unexpected manner: *the kind of person who's hungry at the moment*. This would not be taken as a serious response.  And you'd expect the intonation to connote exaggeration, or humor.  *Hungry* would likely be spoken with a rising-then-falling tone.

Your use of *trapped* as a *kind* is similar.  Being trapped is not a fundamental quality of an animal; it's a temporary condition.